# underscore get nested item by id

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following data structure, that contains categories as the top level followed by optional groups and then chart objects which will represent graph data.

Using underscore, or vanilla js I would like to get a particular chart object by its id. I have tried using combinations of _.flatten and _.find but am getting no where.

If its possible to also get a count of charts in a category, based on a charts id that would be awesome.

```
 {
   "categories":[
      {
         "title":"category 1",
         "id":"cat1",
         "groups":[
            {
               "title":"group 1",
               "id":"grp1",
               "charts":[
                  {
                     "title":"chart 1",
                     "id":"chart1",
                     "type":"line"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"category 2",
         "id":"cat2",
         "charts":[
            {
               "title":"chart 2",
               "id":"chart2",
               "type":"line"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"category 3",
         "id":"cat3",
         "charts":[
            {
               "title":"chart 3",
               "id":"chart3",
               "type":"line"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive function that will do deep search and return desired result.

```js
var obj = {"categories":[{"title":"category 1","id":"cat1","groups":[{"title":"group 1","id":"grp1","charts":[{"title":"chart 1","id":"chart1","type":"line"}]}]},{"title":"category 2","id":"cat2","charts":[{"title":"chart 2","id":"chart2","type":"line"}]},{"title":"category 3","id":"cat3","charts":[{"title":"chart 3","id":"chart3","type":"line"}]}]}

function findObj(data, id) {
  var result = [];

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach(function(e) {
      result = result.concat(findObj(e, id))
    })
  } else if (typeof data == 'object' && !Array.isArray(data)) {
    var f = null;
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(e) {
      if (e == 'id' && data[e] == id) f = data;
    })

    if (f != null) {
      result.push(f);
    } else {
      Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        if (typeof data[key] == 'object') {
          result = result.concat(findObj(data[key], id));
        }
      })
    }
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(findObj(obj, 'grp1'))
console.log(findObj(obj, 'chart1'))
console.log(findObj(obj, 'cat1'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what i need. Ill probably move results outside of this function so that I can search results to check if its already there or not

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nested loop to search your data tree.

- Loop through all `categories`
- Loop through each `groups` array
- If there isn't a group array, make a temporary one: `[{charts: cat.charts }]`
- Loop through charts

Using `.some` or `.find` should enable you to return on the first result. You can change the code to reflect the style you prefer, but it's important to realise there are only two things you need to know to get your result:

- How to iterate over an array
- How to select an object's property

```js
var data={categories:[{title:"category 1",id:"cat1",groups:[{title:"group 1",id:"grp1",charts:[{title:"chart 1",id:"chart1",type:"line"}]}]},{title:"category 2",id:"cat2",charts:[{title:"chart 2",id:"chart2",type:"line"}]},{title:"category 3",id:"cat3",charts:[{title:"chart 3",id:"chart3",type:"line"}]}]};

var result;

data.categories.find(
  cat => (cat.groups || [{ charts: cat.charts }]).find(
    group => group.charts.find(
      chart => {
        if (chart.id === "chart3") {
          result = chart;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })))

console.log(result);
```

If you're planning to do a lot of searches like these, you can create a `Map` or hash object that stores an array of items by an `id` key. Check out some of the questions in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) to see examples on how to do this.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll take a look now

Comment: Probably should have said that this will be used in a browser that doesn't support es6. very interesting though

Comment: You can replace the arrow functions like `function(cat) { return (cat.gr...etc`. `Array.prototype.find` has been around for a while, you can check its support here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have to support IE but this is a really elegant solution